# Workaround for Youtube API?

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

I know this might have been asked before, but this is a special case I am involved into..

**IMPORTANT**
I need to do this inside a separate class, not an activity. Actually my class extends a BaseViewPagerAdapter wrote by someone else..

The idea is that, I can't use YoutubePlayerView because I can not extend YoutubeBaseActivity.

I also tried using YoutubePlayerSupportFragment, same not working because I can't get the refernce for the  from my XML file...

I did try something like this

```
public class YTVideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {
private final static String TAG = "YoutubeVideoFragment";
private static final String DEV_KEY = "key";
private static String id;
private YouTubePlayer mPlayer;
public static YTVideoFragment newInstance(String url){
    YTVideoFragment videoFragment = new YTVideoFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("uri", url);
    videoFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    videoFragment.init(0);

    Log.i(TAG, "new Instance FINAL ");
    return videoFragment;

}

public void init(final int time) {
    initialize(DEV_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            mPlayer = youTubePlayer;
            Log.i(TAG, "-=onInitializationSuccess=-");
            mPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
            id = getArguments().getString("url");
            if (!b){
                mPlayer.loadVideo(id, time);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            Log.i(TAG, "-=onInitializationFailure=-");
            Log.e(TAG, youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

}

And I made an instance of this into the class that extends BaseViewPageAdapter and tried to do

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youtube = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
                youtube.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment,youtube);
```

But there I get an error that replace function is applied on a null object reference ..

If you have any suggestion, or idea how I could make it work on this particular case I would be grateful

Comment: I think you need to change
  
`youtube.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment,youtube);` to `activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment,youtube);`

Comment: @sunil I can't get the activity...because I am not in a activity class

Comment: Then you need to pass activity or context instance to this class.

Comment: Can you explain more ? Or, at least give me an example

Comment: In which class you are doing this ?. How are you initilizing this class ?. During intilization just pass '`context` ' or '`activity`'  like this `ClassWhereTransaction f = new ClassWhereTransaction(activity);`

Comment: Yea, well the thing is that this class I am working on is something like this
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseViewPagerAdapter<EventImageOrVideo>

That's why I said I can't get it..

Comment: But you can pass activity to adapter right.?

Comment: Actually I think I already do it :D This is the call
imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), images, eventIdResponse, eventData,
                eventDetailsFragment);

Comment: The thing now is that, my 2nd param from replace() has to be Fragment but my class return YTVideoFragment..

Comment: `YTVideoFragment` extends `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`  which again extends `Fragment`. It's some other issue check if your imports are same.. i,e  check if `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in imports in both classes.

Comment: imports are fine...I think that simply what I want to get is not possible :(

Comment: Also, was trying to set this

youtube.setTargetFragment(parentFragment.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yt_fragment));

but I need android.support.v4.app.Fragment, and in my case that is Fragment. This is killing me, spent whole day with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to make it work on my context like this

First of all, I changed my YTVideoFragment class to extends Fragment

```
public class YoutubeFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String API_KEY = DateUtils.getDeveloperKey();


private static String VIDEO_ID;


public void setVideoID(String id){
    VIDEO_ID = id;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_layout, container, false);


    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();


    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();


    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                player.play();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
            // YouTube error
            String errorMessage = error.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

And made an instance of that class where I needed it like this

```
YoutubeFragment youtubeFragment = new YoutubeFragment();
                youtubeFragment.setVideoID(eventData.getYoutube_id());
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayout, youtubeFragment)
                        .commit();
```

I have to mention here, that being inside a BaseViewPagerAdapter I had to cast my context to (FragmentActivity) in order to be able to call getSupportFragmentManager();

Frame layout XML which will replace a VideoView inside my main XML file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/youtube_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```