# Why is YouTube Media Player not stopping?

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

Refering to [Workaround for Youtube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882164/workaround-for-youtube-api) code which I made it work as expected(**check my answer to the question**) with only one problem: When I go back, the Youtube Player is still playing.

I tried Overriding onPause() function from Fragment class but is not working..
Also within another class, I have myOnBackPressed() function which handle the adapter and fragments..

```
public void myOnBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (eventDetailsFragment == null || fragmentManager == null)
        return;
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(eventDetailsFragment).remove(eventDetailsFragment).commit();
    fragmentManager.popBackStack();

    getChildFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(R.id.event_list_frame, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    ((EventListActivity) getActivity()).menuRestoreClickListener();
    ((EventListActivity) getActivity()).menuDefaulClickListener();
    if (titleBefore != null && !titleBefore.isEmpty())
        toolbar.setTitle(titleBefore);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu));

}
```

What I am actually trying, is to make the player stops from within this function

Any idea would be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: I am not specific about the youtube video.But in  MediaPlayer there is stop function to stop the MediaPlayer.Can't you use the MediaPlayer stop function?   player.stop();

Comment: Nah, I can't make it this way. It doesn't have a stop() function. Also, I might have found the solution...and I think it is related to the backstack of the fragments. Will come with an answer if I can fix it this way. thx

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, the problem was with the backstack

I just had to pop the fragment containing Youtube Player from the stack

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();
supportFragmentManager.popBackStack();
```